# jQuery find all element by some attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have body from some html doc. Now I would like to get all elements which have a `style` attribute. How can I do this?
Currently doing this in **Javascript**

```
var getTags = document.getElementByTagName(*)
var styleArray = [];
for(var i = 0 ; i < getTags.length; i++) {
  console.log(getTags[i]);
  var attr  = getTags[i].getAttribute('style');
  console.log(attr);
  if(attr != null) {
    styleArray.push(attr);
  }

}
console.log(styleArray);
return styleArray;
```

Comment: Use an attribute selector... `$('[style]')`.

Comment: in js you can write: document.querySelectorAll('[style]').forEach(function(ele, idx) {console.log(ele.textContent);})